# Laptop unable access internet after a while when connected to mobile hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, hotspot, mobile-phone

My Laptop (HP Notebook 440 G2) when connected to my mobile hotspot shared from Redmi 3S Prime shows Limited Access (No Internet Access) a few minutes (during which I am able to access internet) after connection. If I reconnect again I will get internet access for first few minutes. What could be the problem. Please comment if I have to add any more details to my question.

Comment: That's likely to be a problem in your mobile provider's network. It happens to me occasionally (I lose DNS).

Comment: I am abled to use internet in mobile even when in Laptop it shows Limited Access. If a reconnect the wifi in laptop again I can access internet for a few minutes.

Comment: I fixed this issue. When I changed my hotspot name this issue got fixed automaticaly.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

this issue got fixed. When I changed my hotspot name this issue got fixed automaticaly. –